# Please suggest the correct xpath for the below HTML

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<div class="alert ui-pnotify-container alert-warning ui-pnotify-shadow" style="min-height: 16px;"><div class="ui-pnotify-closer" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden; display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Close"></span></div><div class="ui-pnotify-sticker" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden; display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause" title="Stick"></span></div><div class="ui-pnotify-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></div><h4 class="ui-pnotify-title">Confirmation Needed</h4><div class="ui-pnotify-text">You are currently logged in from another browser.<br>Are you sure to log-off the other session?</div><div style="margin-top:5px;clear:both;text-align:right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Ok</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Cancel</button></div>
```

I need to click ok

Comment: You did not even include any HTML in your question.

Comment: How about reading your HTML, noticing which tag is inside which, doing a few experiments, and learning how to construct an xpath yourself? It's knowledge that will serve you along the way.

Comment: @RealSkeptic :thanks for your piece of mind we reach for help only there is inneed

Comment: You need to provide full HTML to get xpath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797348/selenium-command)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this may help:

1. Use xPaths in this case.
2. Use google chrome's built in developer tool for this
3. Place your cursor on the element
4. Press *Ctrl+Shift+C*
5. Click the Element
6. That clicked Element's code is highlighted in the short window on the bottom
7. Right-Click on highlighted code
8. Select *Copy > Copy XPath*

Here it is you have copied the xPath for that specific element. This is shown in the image:

[Click to see how to copy xPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHzoE.png)

Reference: [Selenium Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797348/selenium-command/40492154#40492154)

Comment: Never a fan of this technique. When you use this feature your paths often look like:      //div[5]//span[3]/button[1] and this is bad. One change by a developer adding in a new div, span or button kills your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below for ok and cancel. Is this in a popup iframe by chance?

```
 //button[contains(text(), 'Ok')]
 //button[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"//div[@class='alert ui-pnotify-container alert-warning ui-pnotify-shadow']//button[.='Ok']"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='alert ui-pnotify-container alert-warning ui-pnotify-shadow']//button[.='Ok']"}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)(Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 4.4.0-34-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @Harri Have you tried to run the xpath in your browser directly. I copied your code snippet and it works for me. Can you try this "//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-default')][.='Ok']". Assuming you have only one Ok button with similar class value. Using contains for class attribute as there end spaces in the value.

Comment: @Grasshopper no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-default')][.='Ok']"}

Comment: I have tried it directly on chrome and firefox with the code you have sent and both work. I got no more ideas for you.