# Trying to select element by xpath with Selenium but getting error "Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape the list of followings for a given instagram user. This requires using Selenium to navigate to the user's Instagram page and then clicking "following". However, I cannot seem to click the "following" button with Selenium.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/beforeeesunrise/'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a').click()
```

However, this results in a `NoSuchElementException`. I copied the xpath from the html, tried using the class name, partial link and full link and cannot seem to get this to work! I've also made sure that the above xpath include the element with a "click" event listener.

UPDATE: By logging in I was able to get the above information. However (!), now I cannot get the resulting list of "followings". When I click on the button with the driver, the html does not include the information in the pop up dialog that you see on Instagram. My goal is to get all of the users that the given username is following.

Comment: In Chrome, if you inspect the element and use the "Copy XPath" feature, the XPath it gives is this, which is different from the one in your question: `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/span/button` Does that work?

Comment: @RandomDavis This is the not the button for the list of followings, this is the "Follow" button. What I wrote above is the result of using "Copy XPath" on the "Followings" button.

Comment: Are you actually logged into instagram in your selenium browser session?

Comment: @alecxe I had to be logged in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different XPath. I've verified this is unique on the page.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'following')]")
```

Comment: I tried as xpath specified
`//a[contains(.,'following')]` using the chrome console. A parentheses less from the one that is mentioned by @jeffc. The link having the text "following" is highlighted in the Chrome Console.

Comment: @stupidnetizen Yep, that extra set of parens was a mistake. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct X Path.

Use the following link to get perfect X Paths to access web elements and then try.

[Selenium Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797348/selenium-command/40492154#40492154)

Hope this helps to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the main goal of `selenium` to provide rich functionalities, from a web-scraping perspective, to find elements on the page, so the better option is to delegate this task to a specific tool, like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). After we find what we're looking for, then, we can ask for `selenium` to interact with the element.

The bridge between `selenium` and `BeautifulSoup` will be this amazing function below that I found [here](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf). The function gets a single `BeautifulSoup` element and generates a unique XPATH that we can use on `selenium`.

```
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import itertools

def xpath_soup(element):
    """
    Generate xpath of soup element
    :param element: bs4 text or node
    :return: xpath as string
    """
    components = []
    child = element if element.name else element.parent
    for parent in child.parents:
        """
        @type parent: bs4.element.Tag
        """
        previous = itertools.islice(parent.children, 0, parent.contents.index(child))
        xpath_tag = child.name
        xpath_index = sum(1 for i in previous if i.name == xpath_tag) + 1
        components.append(xpath_tag if xpath_index == 1 else '%s[%d]' % (xpath_tag, xpath_index))
        child = parent
    components.reverse()
    return '/%s' % '/'.join(components)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=YOUR_CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(url = 'https://www.instagram.com/beforeeesunrise/')
source = driver.page_source

soup = bs(source, 'html.parser')
button = soup.find('button', text=re.compile(r'Follow'))
xpath_for_the_button = xpath_soup(button)

elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_for_the_button)
elm.click()
```

### ...and works!

( but you need writing some code to log in with an account)

[image]

Comment: This answer makes no sense... "It's not the main goal of selenium to provide rich functionalities to find elements on the page". Sure it is... Selenium was built to automate the browser. Beautiful Soup was created to scrape HTML. You wrote 20 lines of code for BS to prove that writing one line using Selenium was inefficient?!?

Comment: You are absolutely wrong.  The Selenium's functionalities to search for elements on the page will not be enough in any realistic scenario when you are web scraping a complex page like Instagram or Facebook. The purpose of Selenium is not to be a web scraping tool. If you want a script to interact with another people's website, you will need an HTML parser.

Comment: ...otherwise, you are just bad guessing.